# htaccess rewriterule add another page url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please give me for this one full code to redirect `www.example.com/test/forder/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the `test` in the url you need to specify for it to be kept. This should do it for you.

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/$ /test/$1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /test/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /test/$1/ [R=301, L]
```

Comment: # remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Please give me for this one full code to redirect www.example.com/test/forder/

Comment: I'm sorry, but I won't understand that comment?

Comment: Acctually thanks friend. thanks thanks. Now it's right. :) thanks

Comment: if i can how to vote you. i dnt know about this site.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Comment: if can please help me for this one also.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888986/htaccess-get-code-and-redirect-with-php

Comment: if u can plz help me for this post .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002755/getting-value-and-redirect-with-htaccess

Comment: help me this post plzz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025518/removing-trailing-slash-for-sub-directory-url-indexing