# Removing trailing slash for sub directory url indexing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, slash

```
example.com/contact.php  <- I want to like this -> example.com/contact
```

and this also want...

```
example.com/contact/ (havent real directory. want to redirect /contact)
example.com/contact.(any extension redirect to /contact)
```

i want to like this.. plz help me for this one

if have real directory want to go there...

Edit :

`example.com/watch.php?id=1995/english-videos` this link is not work.. and i want to redirect like this `example.com/contact` dont want slash. and i want to work this link `example.com/watch.php?id=1995/english-videos`

/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^col3negmovie.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.col3negmovie\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]


Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^col3negmovie\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.col3negmovie.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+watchnew1\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ watch/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^watch/(.+?)/?$ watchnew1.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# remove .php extension 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# add .php extension internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

`example.com/watch.php?id=1995/english-videos` not work :( other link i want like this `example.com/contact` , `example.com/about` but this link want like that

Comment: Why do you want to remove trailing slash from real directories? This is big security risk if that directory doesn't have default `index.php`.

Comment: oops!! why? what the problem? can u describe me

Comment: I already wrote the reason why it is a risk.

Comment: In general avoid `DirectorySlash Off` anywhere in your paths.

Comment: post edited.. plz help for this one

Comment: So `/contact/` is not a real directory?

Comment: at present have real directory.. but now i deleted it. now its have on /contact.php like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complete .htaccess can be like that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^col3negmovie\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+watchnew1\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ watch/%1? [R=301,L]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# remove .php extension 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^watch/(.+?)/?$ watchnew1.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# add .php extension internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: whats the mean of last one # add .php extension internally

Comment: work but its redirect to like this /contact/  but i want to /contact like this

Comment: have some problem.. like this links not work :( example.com/watch.php?id=1995/english-videos

Comment: Can you post your latest .htaccess in question.

Comment: Hmm I don't see .htaccess in your question. I need to go for some work and I will come back later to check.

Comment: sry sry. now ok. now you see it :(

Comment: I will get back to you in few hours as I have some important work to finish.